# the meaning of with one's own

Tags: meaning

> In fact it is the soul of mathematics to carry out such a dialogue with one's own proof.

&

> We're talking about a perfectly innocent and delightful activity of the human mind-a dialogue with one's own mentality.

What does the author mean by "with one's own proof" and "with one's own mentality" in the above sentences?

Comment: Basically it means talking to yourself (only in a meaningful way -- not psychotic).  Note that "one's own" has a different connotation in other contexts, meaning your own family or people.

Comment: Don't ask about "with one's own".  Ask about "one's own proof" or "one's own mentality".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word ['one'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one) means any person, but not a particular person. [Definition under 'C1']

You can often substitute the word 'you'.

Examples:

One has an obligation to one's friends. ["You have an obligation to your friends"]

One ought to make the effort to vote. ["You should make the effort to vote"]

**On one's own** means 'on your own', 'by yourself', 'alone'.

**one's own proof** means **your** proof: not anyone else's proof.

**one's own mentality** means your thoughts, your way of thinking, your mind.